# Inspect point cloud saved with google cloud anchor

Tags: arcore, point-clouds, android-augmented-reality

Does google provide a way to visualize the actual point cloud saved when hosting a cloud anchor? It will be very helpful for understanding how many anchors I need to cover a certain area. Considering the users may come from different directions.

The documentation says

> A dataset containing visual data for the anchor is uploaded to Google servers.
> This dataset contains visual data seen by the device recently. Moving the device around a bit to capture the area around the anchor from different viewpoints before hosting will result in better localization.

`ArSession_estimateFeatureMapQualityForHosting` can also tell the current quality - insufficient/sufficient/good

I want to get the actual points being saved.

`ArPointCloud_getData` returns a set of points within the current camera view. Obviously google saves more than just the current frame. It's also possible to collect all points for the current session. But I doubt that google saves all of them considering they can be far away from the anchor being hosted.

Question: how to get the cloud points being saved during google cloud anchor hosting?